# "As...." Structure

Tags: word-meaning, as, analogy

More confusion about the "*as...*" structure:

> 1 People affect laws ***as*** laws affect people.
>   2 People view laws ***as*** laws affect people.

I have a feeling that they mean, respectively:

> 3 People affect laws ***in the same way*** that laws affect people.
>   4 People view laws ***with respect to the way*** laws affect people.

So, the two "*as*" really mean different things?

Comment: Are these made-up sentences? Specially 2 and 4 don't sound good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the two as' could be interpreted as meaning different things. Note that you are using different verbs ("affect" and "view"), which changes context of "as" and thus its meaning. Using "as" in sentences 1 and 2 makes them ambiguous, so using more precise expressions, as in sentences 3 and 4, would help avoid confusion.